# limit histogram output ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm fairly new to R and the ggplot2 package.  I am trying to create a simple histogram of different cities students are coming from for an after school program.  My code thus far is this

```
cities.hist=ggplot(data,
  aes(x=reorder(City, City, function(x)-length(x))))+
  geom_histogram()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))
```

this generates a large histogram with many cities only being counted once.  Is there a ggplot2 function to only display output given a threshold of counts?  I.E. only plot cities that have a count of 5 or more.

I'd like to avoid reordering the actual dataframe if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not a built-in ggplot way to do this. What you should do is just give ggplot the subset of your data that you want plotted. One way to do it using base functions is like this:

```
cities.hist=ggplot(data = subset(as.data.frame(table(data$City)), Freq > 1, select = City),
  aes(x=reorder(City, City, function(x)-length(x))))+
  geom_histogram()+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))
```

The other option would be to calculate a frequency table outside of ggplot (you could use `as.data.frame(table(...)` as above or something more syntactically friendly like `dplyr`) and then plot that with `y = freq` inside your aesthetic mapping and `stat = "identity"` inside the `geom_histogram` call. Something like this:

```
require(dplyr)
data %.% group_by(City) %.% summarize(freq = n()) %.%
    ggplot(aes(x = reorder(City, City, function(x)-length(x)),
               y = freq)) +
    geom_bar(stat = "identity") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 60, hjust = 1))
```

Comment: thanks, I kinda figured that there wouldn't be a way to do this from a strictly visual standpoint.  appreciate the insight